# Are host-named site collections required to use the app model?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, hnsc

My understanding is the HNSCs are recommended because as this technet article states

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952.aspx

> This architecture is recommended to deploy sites because it is the
>   same architecture that the Office 365 environment uses. Consequently
>   this is the most heavily tested configuration. New features, including
>   the App model and Request Management, are optimized for this
>   configuration, and it is the most reliable configuration going
>   forward.

However, are HNSCs required to take advantage of the App Model or is it a strong recommendation?

I've heard that they are required but I have not been able to find any documentation to back that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not required and you can use path-based site collections instead.  They're recommended due to scaling (and as we've heard, to make it easier to migrate to O365).

Comment: What are you referring to when you say "due to scaling"? Is it the Number of site collections?

Comment: It is an issue of multiple Web Applications v. Host Named Site Collections (and a single Web Application).  Web Applications do not scale like HNSC in terms of number of vanity URLs one can have.